Sequelize (Aurora Postgres) with RDS Proxy on Lambda
I am trying to use the AWS RDS Proxy on my lambda to proxy our database (Aurora Postgres). I can connect with Sequelize to my DB directly, but I am unable to connect with the proxy. I wasn't able to find any proxy-specific instructions for Sequelize, but it seemed like all I needed for RDS proxy to work is to switch the host from the DB endpoint to the proxy endpoint. Not sure if relevant, but I am using the Serverless Framework v4 too.
The lambda functions, proxy, and DB are in a VPC and are in the same security group and subnet.
When I check the connection with authenticate() (or make any query), I see a nm [SequelizeConnectionError]: Connection terminated unexpectedly error.
This is my attempt:
const sequelize = new Sequelize(credentials.db_name, credentials.username, credentials.password, {
  host: credentials.proxy_endpoint, // credentials.db_endpoint - using db_endpoint here works
  port: 5432,
  dialect: 'postgres'
})

I have seen mention of needing to use code like this (below) to get a signed auth token, but I've only seen examples for mySQL, so I'm not sure how it would be used in the constructor for Postgres and the docs have made minimal mention.
  const signer = new Signer({
    hostname: credentials.db_host,
    port: 5432,
    region: credentials.region,
    username: credentials.username
  })

  const token = await signer.getAuthToken()

If there is any other clarifying information I can provide, please let me know. Thank you in advance.
